# Black Screen after changing .config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

Tags: reboot, lxsession

After opening .config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart it approximately looked like this

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi @pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi 
@xscreensaver -no-splash @point-rpi @lxterminal -e python3 /home/pi/Workspace/MTCNN_Tensorflow/Bildaufnahme_tensorflow
```

I made some line breaks so it looks like this:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi 
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi 
@xscreensaver -no-splash 
@point-rpi 
@lxterminal -e python3 /home/pi/Workspace/MTCNN_Tensorflow/Bildaufnahme_tensorflow
```

But after reboot my desktop is gone and I only got a black screen with a mouse cursor. How can I reset the .config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart file so I get my old desktop back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had SSH, you could go back and rewrite it back to the original.

If you can access your files, back them up on a USB, and reinstall your version of Raspbian.

I would like it for you to provide picture so I can give more to this answer.

Comment: Luckily I could still access to my files and I've backed them up. I will reinstall my Raspbian. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used *LXDE* so far but from a graphical user interface usually you can get to a text console by pressing `{ctrl}{alt}F1` (..F2-F6). When you can switch to it then login and repair the settings. You can go back to the GUI with `{alt}F7` but in your case there is only a black screen with blinking cursor so you should reboot.

Comment: I didn't know this comments. I will keep them in mind. Thank you.

Comment: @RamónWilhelm Only to have  it in mind for me: does it also work on *LXDE*?